# I am very interested in writing my M.Sc. thesis with Latex, and have question:

Tags: thesis, tutorials

I am writing my M.Sc. thesis in biochemistry, which has mathematics. I am new to latex, but I am greatly interested in it. I am watching/reading tutorials but was wondering if the community could recommend a good set of video lectures/pdf to write a document such as a thesis?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/15925 for a start on general learning material.  You will also find a link there to Marc van Dongen, whose home page contains some course material.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that once you have a handle on creating documents, syntax, compiling and workflow, check with your department for a template. Chances are they provide a latex template that the graduate committee/faculty wants.

Comment: @masfenix Thank you for your input! So, templates have predefined characteristics, right?

Comment: Essentially. Mine just came with predefined page margins, title page, a table of contents, and an example bib style. I've seen some very strict templates to very lenient ones. Again, don't worry about this until you have a good grasp on Latex (it has a steep learning curve) but keep it in mind for your actual thesis.

Comment: Which languages are possible for you?

Comment: @MaxNoe English or French. :)